# Django filtering different parents in template

Tags: python, django, templates

I considered a evaluation Model in my project, which is like

```
class Evaluation(models.Model):
    question        = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    value           = models.IntegerField('Value')
    creator         = models.ForeignKey(User)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.value)
```

In my template, I would like to display the different Evaluations in a table like that

```
| question1 | creator1  : evaluation of creator1
            | creator2  : evaluation of creator2
-------------------------------------------------
| question2 | creator1  : evaluation of creator1
            | creator2  : evaluation of creator2
...
```

For that I have to distinguish the creators in my queryset, related on the question.

Unfortunately I was unable to create a filter or grouping, that did what I want.
How can I easily select the creators and their evaluation depending on the referenced question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the `{% regroup %}` templatetag (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup), applied to an `Evaluation` queryset ordered by `question`, and preferably using `select_related()` (to avoid the N+1 queries problem)

```
# views.py

def myview(request):
   context = {
      "evaluations":Evaluation.objects.order_by("question", "creator").select_related()
      }
    return render(request, "mytemplate.html", context)
```

and your template:

```
# mytemplate.html

    {% regroup evaluations by question as questions_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for question in questions_list %}
      <li>{{ question.grouper }}
        <ul>
          {% for evaluation in question.list %}
          <li>{{ evaluation.creator }}: {{ evaluation }}
          {% endfor %}
        </ul>
      </li>  
     {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```